# Community wiki question: Should we avoid them?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

As I was observing I didn't see any CW questions in Linguistics. So I was thinking about posting general questions for community wiki. These question are helpful for both new users and advanced users. Sample questions can be:

- What are some general textbooks in linguistics?
- What are some good pre-print servers for linguistics?

Are these types of questions accepted in Linguistics SE?

Answer (score 2):

Generally question that generate long lists or non-objective answers are prone to be closed as such, so I'd advise against. The SE network is not built for that kind of questions, but rather for more focused questions with a specific problem or point.

Comment: But what about wiki? Community? Large amount of data? Etc. imagine if we had a list of websites that were a corpus compilation, wasn't that a step towards reducing the number of questions regarding resource request...but again this is just an example, and yes it would be too long. But let's focus on the bright side, would't that reduce the number of basic questions?

Comment: @Adel Community Wiki is intended for when a special case comes up, not as a loophole for asking questions that usually wouldn't be accepted. :P Sorry, I don't make the rules, but I'm here to enforce them. See also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334/176533), it touches very well on this topic. My suggestion would be for you to circumvent the problem by asking a question that is specific but still helps you solve your problem. There are other such questions, you can look into them to see how you can do it. If you have doubts, you can ask here to check if your question works.

Comment: My inquiry was about the philosophy of not doing that. You said that we shouldn't post questions that are not specific, right? But why? I remember I saw a post on Stackoverflow which was titled something like this "What are some hidden features of Python" the question got so many good answers that they made an FAQ for it. What I'm trying to say is that I see a lot of newbie question regarding linguistics that I feel a place for some general QAs (or on another suggestion we could encourage users to edit and read tag wikis for this purpose.)

Comment: The mentioned question is this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python

Comment: @Adel That question is not only closed but also locked! Also, in the past any question with a lot of answers was automatically changed to community wiki. This is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki questions/answers are sometimes useful on Meta sites because:

1. List questions are allowed
2. The edit suggestion system is only used on the main sites

Marking a question or answer as community wiki allows other low rep users to edit posts.

List questions are generally discouraged across the entire SE network, but each site can decide for itself if there will be any exceptions. For example, this site allows list-of-languages questions.

I don't think your suggested questions would be worth making an exception to the general rule of no list questions.